# close colorbox and redirect parent window to a specific url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, colorbox

I am trying to get colorbox (iframe) to close and for it to redirect the parent window to a specific page that is dynamically depending on the image that is being displayed in the colorbox. So basically each image with have a link next to so the user can click to go to the owner of the image profile.

I have got it so it closes the colorbox but not redirecting the parent window.

```
<a href='#' onclick='parent.$.colorbox.close(); window.parent.location.href=linkurl;'> owner profile</a>
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: There are like hundreds of questions about redirecting from iframe (think we get one every day), just use the search feature next time, please...

Comment: thanks Stefan, yes I have just spend a couple of hours going through them and could not find one that was using a link, as most are using forms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" id="myLink">click</a>

jQuery('#myLink').click(function(){
  jQuery.colorbox.close();
  window.location.href = 'http://yourlink.com';
});
```

You could probably remove the window.location and just give youre a tag a link.

Comment: ok thanks for the pointers I have alter what you have put and got it to work. `code`$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#myLink').click(function(){
  parent.$.colorbox.close();
  window.parent.location.href='url';

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `window.parent.location.href=linkurl;` with `opener.location.href=linkurl;`

Comment: It Works for me window.parent.location.href=linkurl